# Simplifying square root where all parameters are reals

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I simplify the following expression, with considering that all parameters are reals?

[image]

you can find the code here:

```
-Sqrt[\[Zeta]/Z^2 - (
   2 J Sinh[\[Alpha]1] Sqrt[\[Zeta] \[Eta]^2 - 
     J^2 Sinh[\[Alpha]1]^2])/(Z^2 \[Eta]^2)] + Sqrt[\[Zeta]/Z^2 + (
  2 J Sinh[\[Alpha]1] Sqrt[\[Zeta] \[Eta]^2 - 
    J^2 Sinh[\[Alpha]1]^2])/(Z^2 \[Eta]^2)]
```

Comment: `Assuming[Element[{J, Z, \[Alpha]1, \[Zeta], \[Eta]}, Reals], 
 expr //
  Simplify]` or `Assuming[Element[{J, Z, \[Alpha]1, \[Zeta], \[Eta]}, Reals], 
 expr //
  FullSimplify]`

Comment: I do not see what you expect a simpler expression to look like? Your expression has the form $\sqrt{A+B}-\sqrt{A-B}$. How would this be simplified any more even if $A,B$ are reals? What do you want this to be simplified to?